# Truncating a 2D array for a given tolerance [Python]

Tags: python, truncate, svd, truncation

An old question on Singular Value Decomposition lead me to ask this question:
How could I truncate a 2-Dimensional array, to a number of columns dictated by a certain tolerance?

Specifically, please consider the following code snippet, which defines an accepted tolerance of 1e-4 and applies Singular Value Decomposition to a matrix 'A'.

```
#Python
tol=1e-4
U,Sa,V=np.linalg.svd(A)
S=np.diag(Sa)
```

The resulting singular value diagonal matrix 'S' holds non-negative singular values in decreasing order of magnitude.

What I want to obtain is a truncated 'S' matrix, in a way that the columns of the matrix holding singular values lower than 1e-4 would be removed. Then, apply this truncation to the matrix 'U'.

Is there a simple way of doing this? I have been looking around, and found some solutions to the problem for Matlab, but didn't find anything similar for Python. 
For Matlab, the code would look something like:

```
%Matlab
tol=1e-4
mask=any(Sigma>=tol,2);
sigRB=Sigma(:,mask);
mask2=any(U>=tol,2);
B=U(:,mask);
```

Thanks in advance. I hope my post was not too messy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly. If my solution is not what you ask for, please consider adding an example to your question.

The following code drops all columns from array `s` that consist only of values smaller than `tol`.

```py
s = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, .9, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, .5, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, .4, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, .3, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, .2]
])

print(s)

tol = .4
ind = np.argwhere(s.max(axis=1) < tol)

s = np.delete(s, ind, 1)

print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.9 0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.5 0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.4 0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.3 0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.2]]


[[1.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.9 0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.5 0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.4]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]]
```

I am applying `max` to axis 1 and then using `np.argwhere` to get the indices of the columns where the max value is smaller than `tol`.

Edit: In order to truncate the columns of matrix 'U', so it coincides in size with the reduced matrix 'S', the following code works:

```
k = len(S[0])
Ured = U[:,0:k]
Uredsize = np.shape(Ured) # To check it has worked
print(Uredsize)
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was asking. I tried your solution and it worked. Thank you very much. How would you then apply the truncation of the same rows to the matrix 'U'? 
I don't think argwhere would work with this, seeing that the values of 'U' are not in order. 
Would it be possible to do something like: Define a variable with the number of columns of 'S' and then somehow truncate matrix 'U' to the number of columns defined?

Comment: When I understand your matlab code correctly, you are using the way for U. that would be `ind2 = np.argwhere(u.max(axis=1) < tol); b = np.delete(u, ind2, 0)`. Not sure if that is correct. I would have guessed you have to remove the rows instead of the columns for U. In that case changing to `axis=0` should work.

Comment: No, sorry; I think I didn't express myself correctly. The idea would be to remove the same number of columns in 'U' that I removed in 'S'.
The tolerance is only useful in 'S' because the values are in decreasing order. 'U' would just have to have the same dimensions as 'S'.

Comment: Solved. I will add the solution to my second question as an edit to your post, if that's okay with you.